# How to hardcode CFBundleIdentifier?

Tags: objective-c, macos

what else can I say, how do I hardcode the CFBundleIdentifier in the app ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode the CFBundleIdentifier into the app? OS X designed it to be placed in plist, so if you remove it from the plist and embed it in the app, might cause possible trouble on OS perspective.

Comment: It is something that is recommended for the new mac store to check if the application is actually bought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change `CFBundleIdentifier` during runtime, you can’t unless you write to the application bundle `Info.plist`. That’s bad practice because the application bundle might have been moved to a read-only volume, or had its write permissions limited by the system administrator, or digitally signed to avoid tampering. I guess Launch Services wouldn’t recognise this change instantly and the application would have to be restarted. Furthermore, it is also a reason for rejection by the Mac Apple Store.

On the other hand, if you want to detect tampering of `CFBundleIdentifier`, you can always read its value upon application startup, e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *bundleId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    if (! [bundleId isEqualToString:@"com.yourcompany.yourapp"])
    {
        // Ooops, CFBundleIdentifier doesn’t match
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you might want to obfuscate the code above, including the literal strings. However, in general, you won’t be able to stop a determined adversary.